# Windows 10 asks permission when programs started from taskbar

Tags: windows-10, taskbar, security-warning

Since a few weeks (probably after an update of windows 10) I get this really annoying warning every time I start a program from my taskbar. It is a security warning wanting to know if I am really sure I want to open this file.

I have this at home and at my work, I searched the internet but found nobody with the same problem. I hoped it would be gone after a new update but after two updates I'm getting desperate.

Does anyone have a solution?

[image: screenshot of the warning]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Usually its the UAC. Maybe it was turned off before and the update re-enabled it. Can you provide a screenshot?

P.S. You can turn off the UAC. Goto User Accounts->User Account Control Setting and turn slider all the way down.

Edit: That definitely does not seems to be an alert from UAC.

Edit 2: Seems like your internet options are interfering with your shortcuts. You can disable this security warning to solve the problem. I will also suggest you to scan your computer for vulnerabilities.

Goto
Internet Options > Security > Custom Level > "Launching applications and unsafe files (not secure)" > Enable

Comment: Thanks for your response, I added a screenshot, but it is in Dutch so maybe it won't help you. Also because my windows is in Dutch I cannot seem to find the slider you propose... I'm now trying to get my windows in to English

Comment: I translated it. It says "Although files that you downloaded from the Internet can be useful, this file type can harm your computer. Do not perform this software if you are uncertain about the origin."

Comment: Are you sure its from the taskbar, because it only shows this alert only when you download files from Internet explorer.

Comment: I found the setting and I fiddled around with it and some other settings too. Also restarted my laptop but the issue still remains. Yes I think it is called taskbar, the icons you place in the lower left corner just right from the Windows button.

Comment: I looked around, seems like your internet settings are interfering with your shortcuts somehow. That happens only if you are using the pc with administrative right. Please look iin the original answer for the solution. I have edited it.

Comment: It is true that I run my laptop with an administrator account. And The trick you proposed did work. However, my PC warns me of a huge security risk with this setting. I rather mark these programs as safe one time and leave this setting as it was... Any idea's on that?

Comment: Although those shortcuts are marked as security risk by error from latest windows update(which one I don't know). Just scan your pc and if you will roll back any latest windows updates and start update again. As one of windows update may be compromised and fixed by microsoft.